# How to translate the following simple curl call to R code using RCurl?

Tags: r, rcurl

Consider the following commands (2 examples)

```
curl -H "Accept:text/plain" http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/866350/allrelated 

curl -i -L -H "Accept: application/xml"  http://pub.orcid.org/search/orcid-bio?q=digital-object-ids:"10.1088/0031-9155/58/3/535"
```

The user is able to run those on win7 command line with curl.exe installed. The RCurl package has no vignette and it has a lot of commands to choose from. How do I get the text file and XML file output using RCurl?

Comment: there's now an `rorcid` package https://github.com/ropensci/rorcid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following :

```
mytxt <- getURL("http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/866350/allrelated", httpheader=c(Accept="text/plain"))
```

And :

```
myxml <- getURL('http://pub.orcid.org/search/orcid-bio?q=digital-object-ids:"10.1088/0031-9155/58/3/535"', httpheader=c(Accept="application/xml"))
```

You will find many examples in the `getURL` help page.